# How to represent nested dataframes with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested, data-representation

I have a bunch of time-consuming calculations that take ~5 input parameters (`a,b,c...`). When I run a parameter study, I can summarize all calculations in a pandas DataFrame that would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
parameters = {'a':[1.5,2.3], 'b':[3.1,3.4],'c':[2.5,5.2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(parameters)

df1
     a    b    c
0  1.5  3.1  2.5
1  2.3  3.4  5.2
```

The result of each of these calculations is basically a time series for ~40 variables (`x,y,z...`). The number of time steps is usually around a couple of thousend. This again can be nicely represented using a DataFrame:

```
results = {'x':[0,0.1], 'y':[0,0.5],'z':[0.3,0.3]} 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(results, index=[0,0.1] )                            
df2.index.name = 't'                                                   

df2                                                                    
           x     y      z
t                 
0.0      0.0   0.0    0.3
0.1      0.1   0.5    0.3
```

**Now the question is:** I would like to link the result of each calculation (`df2`) to its representation in `df1`. Ideally, I would be able to use pandas selection and grouping abilities to extract certain calculations *based on their input parameters* and then plot their results (again, ideally using pandas to define what I would like to look at in each results dataframe).

My current approach is to include each result dataframe in a `'results'` column of df1, which in the example can be achieved like this:

```
result_list = [df2,df2]
df1['results'] = result_list
df1
     a    b    c                                            results
0  1.5  3.1  2.5         x    y    z
t                 
0.0  0.0...
1  2.3  3.4  5.2         x    y    z
t                 
0.0  0.0...
```

Although this messes up the formatting of the output, it works reasonably well.

**However, I found many answers that highly discourage this usage of nested dataframes!** And even though the results are all stored in `df1['results']`, I most likely have to rely on looping over this column (i.e. transform it into a list first) for any operations I would like to make.

Does anyone with more experience in data representation have an idea for a different structure, that goes more with the pandas philosophy or uses a different tool altogether?

Comment: Why not use a simple list of dictionaries [{'run': 0, 'parameters': [...], 'results': [...] }, ...] ? You can store and exchange such a list of dicts easily as JSON. DataFrames are great but not for every use case.

Comment: Using a list of nested dicts would be possible. But filtering and showing results interactively (which is what I would like to be able to) would be much more cumbersome.